# Using Zynq in AMP(Asymmetric Multiple Processing) mode

Tags: xilinx, vivado, zynq

There are application notes XAPP 1078 and XAPP 1079 etc which uses Zynq in AMP mode.

In this application notes, we use a repositry sdk_repo to configure FSBL in standalone-amp template.

I would like to know what are the difference between normal 'Zynq-FSBL' template and modified 'Zynq FSBL for AMP' template.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Which version of petalinux and vivado are you using? Xilinx has changed some things in the workflow of getting a working AMP in current versions. However they did not update their reference designs, yet. Using them might lead you into a dead-ended development. 
Xilinx is using OpenAMP for future IPC (current vivado 2015.4 is supporing OpenAMP library templates in its SDK, already). remoteproc on linux has not changed, since it is standard kernel upstream. OpenAMP, however supports some baremetal features, that formerly have not been possible (like booting linux remote from a baremetal/rtos master.
Try to get familiar with the documentation in the docs folder of OpenAMP's github:

https://github.com/OpenAMP/open-amp

If you run into issues using the getting started guide (and I suppose you will) refer to the following thread:
https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/OpenAMP/port-microzed-for-openAMP/td-p/662778

To your question:
I have built an OpenAMP setup for MicroZed with linux master on cpu0 and baremetal on cpu1. I am using the zynq_fsbl.elf created by petalinux (images/linux/zynq_fsbl.elf) and I am fine with it.